# Ansible: Get Particular value from JSON

Tags: json, ansible

I am getting following output in Ansible JSON Format and need to fetch Request ID from it please help

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "op.content": {
        "_links": {
           "self": [
               {
                   "href": "url123"
               }
           ]
        }, 
       "entries": [
            {
               "_links": {
                  "self": [
                       {
                           "href": "url456"
                        }  
                ] 
            }, 
            "values": {
                "Request ID": "abc|abc", 
                "Status": "Assigned"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json_query` filter to get the `Request ID` value of your JSON object. Here is an example of how you could parse it. In my example, I am getting the JSON object from a file, and storing it in a variable called `op_request`. On the `json_query` task, take notice of how you can escape a key that has a dot (`.`) inside:

```
---
- name: Get "Request ID" from JSON
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - ./secret.yml
  vars:
    op_content_file: ./files/op_content.json
  tasks:
    - name: Read JSON file
      set_fact:
        op_content: '{{ lookup("file", op_content_file) }}'

    - name: Get RequestID from op_content variable
      set_fact:
        request_id: "{{ op_content | json_query('\"op.content\".entries[0].values.\"Request ID\"') }}"
```

I hope it helps

Comment: M unable to get o/p still.Please clarify this line.
On the json_query task, take notice of how you can escape a key that has a dot (.) inside:

Comment: Or if you can help me with exact code to fetch Request ID please

Comment: The example I gave works with the same JSON you provided. Put it inside a file, run the playbook and you'll see the answer. Regarding my comment `On the json_query task, take notice of how you can escape a key that has a dot (.) inside:`, it was to bring your attention to the fact that you have a `.` in one of your keys, which you have to escape to be able to parse it using JSON query.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me but a quick question for you. I didnt get why op.content and request id is enclosed in quotes but entries and values are not..

Comment: As I mentioned, is because of the `.` inside the key  `op.content`. The filter `json_quey` uses the dot as a notation to traverse the JSON file. Since you have it as part of a key name, you need to escape it, so `json_query` avoids it.